# BasicHttpContext error message on redirection

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpcomponents

I am using HttpClient to logg in to a web page. The web page redirects to me to another page.

I have handled redirection by the following code :

```
            client.setRedirectStrategy( new DefaultRedirectStrategy(){
                public boolean isRedirected(HttpRequest req, HttpResponse res, HttpContext con){
                    if(res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==302) return true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

I use httpClient 4.1.3 jar and httpCore 4.1.4 jar. My java compiler version is 1.5.

I am getting the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext: method <init>()V not found
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createHttpContext(AbstractHttpClient.java:273)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:797)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
```

Can anyone help me please. I looked at previous stackover flow questions and changed my compiler to version 1.3 and checked but still it gave me same error. i changed httpCore to version 4.0 and checked but still it gave me same error.

If you need any additional information please do let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There must be an older version of `HttpCore` on the classpath. Double-check your project setup.